# Create function that uses tidy eval and the rescale function in R

Tags: r, tidyeval

I want to write a simple function that takes a dataframe and a numeric column (a parameter e.g. called `col` as input. The name of the numeric column should be quoted (like `"mpg"`). I am having some troubles figuring out how I could use the `scales::rescale`-function to map the value of the column (whos name is stored in `col`) to a new interval (e.g. 0 to 1).

I know this works

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(val = sample(1:10, 5, replace = T))
resc = function(df, col){
  df %>% 
    mutate(
      rescaled_value = scales::rescale(.data[[col]])
    )
}
```

But I wanted to do something like this:

```
resc = function(df, col){
  df %>% 
    mutate(
      rescaled_value = scales::rescale({{col}}, to=c(0,1), from=range(.data[[col]]))
    )
}
```

So basically I do not know how to specify the first paramter to the `rescale`-function in a way that works in tidy eval.

Comment: Did you try `scales::rescale(.data[[col]], to=c(0,1), from=range(.data[[col]]))`? I'm not sure why you changed to `{{col}}`

Comment: Also: `from=` is not really needed. It will default to the range of `x` aka `.data[[col]]`.

Comment: `rescaled_value = ({{col}} - min({{col}}))/diff(range({{col}}))` may be just as easy?

Comment: `.data[[col]]` _is_ tidyeval syntax, and the correct one for this use case ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use !!sym like this:

```
resc = function(df, col){
  df %>% 
    mutate(
      rescaled_value = scales::rescale(!!sym(col), from = range(!!sym(col)))
    )
}
```

This also works and is short but does not use tidy eval. It depends on  using %>% and would not work with |> .

```
resc = function(df, col){
  df %>% 
    mutate(
      rescaled_value = scales::rescale(.[[col]], from = range(.[[col]]))
    )
```

}

Comment: Hi, just a note that you can also use `.data[[col]]`. It's the recommended solution as we try to keep `!!` for advanced usage. Also using `.data` is a little safer (the symbol must come from the data frame, there is no risk of hitting a symbol in the current environment unexpectedly when the column is missing from the data frame, a missing column is always an error with `.data`).

Comment: That was already in the question so I think we can assume that an alternative was wanted.

Comment: Thank you all! While I also wanted to just get function working, I was also interested in how tidy eval works here. So thank you for all the comments!:)